# com.dropbox.chooser.android.AppStoreInterstitial expection in Android App

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I got this exception in my Android App in PlayStore

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dropbox.chooser.android.AppStoreInterstitial.setStrings(AppStoreInterstitial.java:165)
com.dropbox.chooser.android.AppStoreInterstitial.access$100(AppStoreInterstitial.java:27)
at com.dropbox.chooser.android.AppStoreInterstitial$NativeFragment.onCreateDialog(AppStoreInterstitial.java:55)
at android.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:398)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Couldn't reproduce it as it doesn't say where exactly in the App it's happening. The App has a feature to upload/download file from Dropbox ; I check those, but it's working fine for me. Tried searching on the Web, but no luck. Can someone please help? What is this issue?

Comment: Would you mind providing some information and code? So for example the Part of `AppStoreInterstatial` on lines 165 and 27 would be interesting, or at least how they're called from your app.

Comment: This will be better served as a bug report to https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact . Please open a ticket there with any details you have, including app name, calling code, SDK version, and Android OS version, if you have it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproduced this. Realized this happens when the user doesn't have the Dropbox App installed in his device.